# react-hot-loader + error boundaries: how to clear error after hot update?

Tags: reactjs, react-hot-loader

Here's my error boundary:

```
export default class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component<Props> {

    state: State = {error: null, errorInfo: null};

    componentDidCatch(error: Error, errorInfo: ErrorInfo) {
        this.setState({
            error: error,
            errorInfo: errorInfo
        })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.errorInfo) {
            return (
                <ErrorContainer>
                    <Title>Runtime Error</Title>
                    <ErrorMessage>{String(this.state.error)}</ErrorMessage>
                </ErrorContainer>
            );
        }

        return this.props.children;
    }
}
```

When my app crashes, it looks like this:

[image]

The problem is when I fix that error, the message never goes away.

It's pretty easy to see why: I've copied the error into the state. The state is never cleared during a hot reload.

My question is: *how* can I clear the error state when there's a hot-reload?

Ideally, it'd only clear the state when a child/descendent is reloaded, but that might be too difficult to determine, so I'd settle for it clearing whenever *any* component reloads. Likely it will just catch again if the error wasn't fixed.

---

Hot reloading is configured using the recommended approach:

```
const App = () => (
    <ErrorBoundary>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <ScrollTop>
                <Container>
                    /* blah blah */

                    <TabContent>
                        <ErrorBoundary>
                            /* blah */
                        </ErrorBoundary>
                    </TabContent>
                </Container>
            </ScrollTop>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </ErrorBoundary>

)

export default hot(module)(App)
```